# Why won't Seaborn install on PyCharm or in the command line?

Tags: linux, python, konsole

When I try to install seaborn in PyCharm by adding the package to my available packages, I receive an error stating

> Non-zero exit code (1)

It provides a proposed solution which is as follows:

> Try to run this command (`pip install seaborn`) from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/usr/bin/python2.7'.

When I run the command in the terminal I receive the following error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-edImGe/matplotlib

The full terminal looks like this:

```
calflan@calflan-MacBookPro:~/Projects/CIS3303$ pip install seaborn
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.                                                          
Collecting seaborn
  Downloading seaborn-0.7.1.tar.gz (158kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 159kB 2.1MB/s 
Collecting scipy (from seaborn)
  Downloading scipy-0.18.1.tar.gz (13.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 13.1MB 48kB/s 
Collecting matplotlib (from seaborn)
  Using cached matplotlib-1.5.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
============================================================================
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.5.3]
                python: yes [2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24)  [GCC
                        5.4.0 20160609]]
              platform: yes [linux2]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.11.0]
              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.6.0]
                  pytz: yes [using pytz version 2016.7]
                cycler: yes [cycler was not found. pip will attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
               tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                        WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
             pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                        mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                        could not be found.  You may need to install the
                        development package.]
                   png: yes [version 1.2.54]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                        found. Using local copy.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                        matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
                        your preferred tool to run the test suite / mock is
                        required to run the matplotlib test suite. Please
                        install it with pip or your preferred tool to run
                        the test suite]
        toolkits_tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                        matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
                        your preferred tool to run the test suite / mock is
                        required to run the matplotlib test suite. Please
                        install it with pip or your preferred tool to run
                        the test suite]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
                qt4agg: yes [installing, Qt: 4.8.7, PyQt: 4.8.7; PySide not
                        found]
               gtk3agg: no  [Requires gtk3 development files to be
                        installed.]
             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires gtk3 development files to be
                        installed.]
                gtkagg: no  [The C/C++ header for gtk (gtk/gtk.h) could not
                        be found.  You may need to install the development
                        package.]
                 tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                        Tk]
                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                   gtk: no  [The C/C++ header for gtk (gtk/gtk.h) could not
                        be found.  You may need to install the development
                        package.]
                   agg: yes [installing]
                 cairo: yes [installing, pycairo version 1.8.8]
             windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: no
           ghostscript: yes [version 9.18]
                 latex: no
               pdftops: yes [version 0.41.0]

OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                  dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

============================================================================
                        * The following required packages can not be built:
                        * freetype

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-edImGe/matplotlib
```

At the top of this log, it says the following:

> You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 9.0.1 is available.
>       You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

So I tried to upgrade pip using the following command: `pip install --upgrade pip` which produced more error which are as follows:

```
calflan@calflan-MacBookPro:~/Projects/CIS3303$ pip install --upgrade pip

You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 7.1.0
    Uninstalling pip-7.1.0:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 640, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 726, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 125, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 314, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 300, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/requires.txt'
```

what am I doing wrong and what must I do in order to install Seaborn?

Comment: Can you successfully remove PIP 7.1 (just remove it, not upgrade it)?

Comment: Do you know the command to do that by any chance? I can't seem to find it online. - Nevermind I have done it using `pip uninstall pip` and no It does not work.

Comment: It has worked now after using `sudo` before the command `pip uninstall pip`

Comment: You should add that as a proper answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the 'pip' version needed to be updated, but the normal command of `pip install --upgrade pip` will not work. This can be solved by uninstalling 'pip' using `sudo pip uninstall pip`.

Once this is done, re-install 'pip' using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build essential
```

Followed by:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Now, you have successfully reinstalled 'pip' (now in it's upgraded form), you can install 'Seaborn' using:

```
pip install seaborn
```

Source: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/02/how-install-pip-ubuntu/

Ignoring the final step as it is not needed (installing virtualenv)

Comment: This does the job well.. it should be an accepted answer @CJF

Comment: Oh..sorry I did not notice that you only have asked the quesiton..hahah @CJF